# Show that $f(E_{\lambda}(g)) \subseteq E_{\lambda}(g)$ if $f \circ g = g \circ f$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, vector-analysis

We have 2 linear functions.

$f: V \to V$ and
$g: V \to V$

Show that for each Eivenvalue $\lambda$ of g we have for the corresponding Eigenspace $E_{\lambda}(g)$:
$$f(E_{\lambda}(g)) \subseteq E_{\lambda}(g)$$

I started off like this:

$$g(E_{\lambda}(g)) \subseteq E_{\lambda}(g)$$
$$f(g(E_{\lambda}(g))) \subseteq f(E_{\lambda}(g))$$
$$\implies g(f(E_{\lambda}(g))) \subseteq f(E_{\lambda}(g))$$

Now I'm stuck, how can I continue? Did I even start this proof correctly?

Comment: Take an element $u \in E_\lambda(g)$ and apply $f$. Then use commutativity of $f$ with $g$ to show that $f(u)$ is in $E_\lambda(g)$.

Comment: I don't quite get how to use commutativity to show this, can you go into some more detail?

Answer (score 2):

Okay I was able to solve it.

Let $x \in E_{\lambda}(g)$

$$g(x) = \lambda x$$
$$f(g(x)) = f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x)$$
$$g(f(x)) = \lambda f(x)$$
$$\implies f(x) \in E_{\lambda}(g)$$

Comment: That's the idea yes. But you can still improve the structure of the answer in order to have a well written solution.

Comment: Yep, that's it! For a more "elegant" answer you can write: $g(f(x)) = f(g(x)) = f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x)$.